# Jetty 8.1.17 - EndPoint making no progress

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am finding the below two warning and info messages on my jetty embedded server. Please let me know how I should resolve this.

EndPoint making no progress
Closing EndPoint making no progress

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 8 is very old.  Upgrade to recent Jetty 9.2 or wait a week for jetty 9.3

cheers